# Can not switch to Doze mode

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am following instructions on this [android page](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) to switch android to doz mode to test my app, I have used a real device as well as emulator. But in both cases when I give the second command once or several times, which is

```
adb shell dympsys deviceidle step
```

it only says Stepped: ACTIVE 
Before giving the commands I turned off/locked the device as well but no use. I wanted how my app behaves in doze mode but nothing seems to work,

I also tried

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle
```

but this gives me the message below.

```
 Unable to go idle; not enabled
```

Please advise. I am using motorola Moto G 2nd generation android 6.0 and also used emulator x86_64 bit image with android studio version 1.5.1

Comment: Hi! Did you solved this problem? I have same problem..

Answer (score 70):

try using

`adb shell dumpsys deviceidle enable`

that should enable the deep and light idle modes, then use

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle
```

Comment: `adb shell dumpsys deviceidle enable` fixed it for me

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Disconnect and reboot your device.
2. Connect device and launch app from Android Studio, switch off the screen.
3. In terminal:

```
adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 2):

try these commands for idle mode in emulator (you can use it in device also but if it is not working on device (clock timer or other reasons try these on emulator)

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle enable
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle
```

to check if device goes in idle mode or not try this command

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle get deep
```

Answer (score 1):

It can sometimes misbehave. When it happend to me i used the command

```
   adb shell dumpsys battery reset
```

This will drain your battery. After letting it charge for sometime i used the below two commands

```
   adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
   adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step
```

Make sure you give the last command multiple times. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Strange. Anyways can you check developer options in your phone and check if stay awake option is switched on.

Comment: It is turned off, but still the same behavior, checking on emulator too, same thing.

Comment: Then maybe its a problem with your system. Did you try restarting your PC?

Comment: how to exit idle mode then?