# When turn on doze mode on an emulator it doesn't work

Tags: android, adb, android-doze, doze

When I turn on doze mode on an android emulator using adb shell it just freeze. I cannot reboot it and emulator restarting doesn't help.

I use the following commands for turn doze mode on:

```
adb shell dumpsys battery unplug

adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step deep
```

And the following to turn it off:

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_WAKEUP

adb shell dumpsys battery reset
```

Comment: I can't be sure, but maybe setting cold boot instead quick boot in emulator settings helps. Or it works from time to time

Comment: It was already answered in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42440619